# Reasons why a website might not appear on webview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I'm trying to make a web view in an app. I've managed to do one, however I'm having trouble with the other. I used the exact same code for both however it doesnt work for the second one. Are there any reasons why it works for one but not the other?

Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSURL (string: "https://acorn.utoronto.ca/")
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

Comment: everything looks fine, could you check that this `@IBOutlet` is referencing the correct storyboard item?

Comment: You should be setting the delegate which you are not. You can check for errors in didFailLoadWithError.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, can you provide more detail on how to do that? I've tried substituting the website with another one without changing the code and it works